# Сложность алгоритма сортировки?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Читаю учебник, в нем есть глава со сложностью алгоритма сортировки

```
 function selection_sort(list)
 for current ← 1 … list.length – 1
   smallest ← current
     for i ← current + 1 … list.length
     if list[i] < list[smallest]
     smallest ← i
   list.swap_items(current, smallest)
```

И там сложность внешнего цикла вычислили как 2n-2

> Внешний цикл совершит n – 1 итераций и в каждой
>   из них выполнит две операции (одно присвоение и один обмен
>   значениями), всего 2n – 2 операций.

Затем сложность внутреннего цикла через формулу Гаусса для суммы последовательности

> В худшем случае условие if всегда соблюдается. Это означает, что
>   внутренний цикл выполнит одно сравнение и одно присвоение (n(n-1))/2
>    раз, отсюда n^2 – n операций.

И причина создания топика:

> В целом стоимость алгоритма 2n – n складывается из операций внешнего цикла и n^2 операций внутреннего
>   цикла. Мы получаем временную сложность: n^2 + n - 2

Не буду уже говорить, что сложности в цитате выше вообще не соответствуют тем, что они сами вывели, сейчас про другое: разве нужно суммировать? В каждом внешнем цикле выполняется внутренний, соответственно должно ведь быть умножение?

Comment: Количество операций внутреннего цикла - уже перемножено. Иначе там никак бы n^2 не получилось. `n^2 - n` - это количество операций внутреннего цикла (уже домножено на количество итераций внешнего), а `2n - 2` - количество операций внешнего цикла (без внутреннего). Далее - именно *суммируем*.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, невнимательно я как-то